# replace a character element of a data frame

Tags: r, replace, dataframe, character, element

I have a data frame and some character misread,

```
example1
1         SABRINA MOCKENHAUPT
2             IRINA MIKITENKO
3         MARILSON DOS SANTOS
4                   RYAN HALL
5                 TIKI GELANA
6            KENTARO NAKAMOTO
7               JAOUAD GHARIB
8                   S…REN KAH
9            CONSTANTINA DITA
```

and I would want to replace some element. For example, replace eighth element `exemple1$exemple1[[8]]<-"SÖREN KAH"`. But it shows me this error

```
In `[[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 8, value = c(57L, 29L, 41L, 54L, 65L,  :invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: try `example1[8] <- "SOREN KAH"`

Comment: yeah, his problem is that he doesn't realise that he's working with factors.

Comment: @Oriol Prat i see that you've never accepted an answer before. If my answer (or any of the others you've recived over the past few momths) solves a problem you ought to accept: it helps the community by marking out the solution to your problem. It also earns you status -- and increases the probability that someone will answer your questions in the future. you do this by selecting the tick to the left of the answer. Upvotes also help by marking what's useful, but they don't earn you status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided a reproducible example, so i'm guessing a little: but it seems that the problem is that `example1` is made up of factors.

Here's a basic guess at `example1`

```
example1 <- as.factor(LETTERS[1:9])
```

when you print your `factor1` you probably see something like the following:

```
R> example1
[1] A B C D E F G H I
Levels: A B C D E F G H I
```

Now if we try and replace any item with a non-factor (something not listed in `levels` above), we will get the following error (which is similar to yours):

```
R> example1[8] <- "KK"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 8, value = "KK") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

but note that you could make a substitution of one listed factor for another -- meaning that `example1[8] <- "A"` is valid.

My guess is that you don't want factors -- you want characters. So you need to coerce `example1` to character. Do this as follows

```
R> example1.ch <- as.character(example1)
```

No your substitution will work:

```
R> example1.ch[8] <- 'kk'
R> example1.ch
[1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "kk" "I"
```

In general, you can use the command `str()` to learn about what your data object is comprised of -- which will help when you get odd errors like this one.

```
R> str(example1)
 Factor w/ 9 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 9
```